# Fmod getDriverInfo falied

Tags: audio, initialization, fmod

all
    I have use fmod component to play sound in win7, I have encountered some proble when initializing the componnet . the code as follows.

```
   FMOD::Memory_Initialize(0, 0, FMOD_AllocCallback,   FMOD_ReallocCallback,     FMOD_FreeCallback);


    result = FMOD::System_Create(&m_pFMOD);
    if (result != FMOD_OK)
    {
        //fprintf(stderr, ERR_NOSOUND, result, FMOD_ErrorString(result));
        DREAMLAND_RUNINFO(L"[FMod] System_Create error:%s", Utf82WideChar(FMOD_ErrorString(result)).c_str());
        m_pFMOD = NULL;
        return false;
    }

    result = m_pFMOD->getVersion(&version);
    if (result != FMOD_OK)
    {
        RUNINFO(L"[FMod] getVersion error:%s", Utf82WideChar(FMOD_ErrorString(result)).c_str());
        m_pFMOD->release();
        m_pFMOD = NULL;
        return false;
    }
    if (version < FMOD_VERSION)
    {
    RUNINFO(L"[FMod]version < FMOD_VERSION error:%s", Utf82WideChar(FMOD_ErrorString(result)).c_str());
        m_pFMOD->release();
        m_pFMOD = NULL;
        return false;
    }
    const int iLength = 1024;
    char szName[iLength] = {0};
    FMOD_GUID sFmodGuid;
    result = m_pFMOD->getDriverInfo(0, szName, iLength, &sFmodGuid);
    if (result != FMOD_OK)
    {
        RUNINFO(L"[FMod]getDriverInfo error:%s", Utf82WideChar(FMOD_ErrorString(result)).c_str());
        m_pFMOD->release();
        m_pFMOD = NULL;
        return false;
    }
    int iMin = 0, iMax = 0;
    result = m_pFMOD->getDriverCaps(0, &caps, &iMin, &iMax, &speakermode);
    if (result != FMOD_OK)
    {
        //fprintf(stderr, ERR_NOSOUND, result, FMOD_ErrorString(result));
        RUNINFO(L"[FMod] getDriverCaps error:%s", Utf82WideChar(FMOD_ErrorString(result)).c_str());
        m_pFMOD->release();
        m_pFMOD = NULL;
        return false;
    }
```

the function getdriverinfo failed, the error string is  14:16:00:729 | [FMod]getDriverInfo error:An invalid parameter was passed to this function. i have read the document of fmod, but the parameter pass to this function , i couldn't find which parameter is error. can any one help me? or give me some tips?

Answer (score 0):

```
int iLength = 1024;
    char szName[iLength] = {0};
    FMOD_GUID sFmodGuid;
    result = m_pFMOD->getDriverInfo(i, szName, szLength, &sFmodGuid,0,0,0);
```

you were missing some parameters